# How to specify a type parameter using <> to create a template class

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have this code:

```
class Grid {
public:
    vector<vector<int> > grid;
    int width;
    int height;

    Grid (int width, int height) width(width), height(height) {
        ...
    }
};
```

It makes a class called `Grid` which is a 2D array of integers. The problem is, however, that at the moment it can *only* be integers, but I want it so it's kind of like the `std::vector` class in which you can use `<>` parentheses to choose the type that it will store. My question is, how can I use these in ***my*** class in order to replace all the current `int`s with any other class.

Also, you might say to look it up but I tried and I could't find anything, probably because I didn't know what to search so if anyone could give me an idea on what this is even called then that'd be helpful too.

Comment: Read a good [programming using C++](http://stroustrup.com/programming.html) book about `template`-s. But teaching that to you would be too long for an answer. So your question is too broad...

Comment: No, my problem is that I need to make a `Grid` of any type

Comment: Make Grid a template

Comment: on top of your class definition put "template<typename T>". You will also have to put this over any methods defined outside of the class body. http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/templates.html

Comment: [Templates](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates). What else?

Answer (score 6):

It seems like you just want to template your `Grid` class:

```
template <typename T>
class Grid {
  public:
    vector<vector<T> > grid;

    // initialize the vector with the correct dimensions:
    Grid (int width, int height)
        : grid(width, vector<double>(height)) {}
};
```

and then instantiate:

```
Grid<double> g(x, y);
```

This will create a `Grid` object where `T` is `double`